# EMR DAG terminates before all steps are completed

Tags: python, airflow

I am using the EMR CreateJobFlow, AddSteps,StepSensor and TerminateJobFlow operators in my DAG to start up an EMR cluster, add steps (2 spark apps, and dist-cp), and terminate when all steps are completed or 1 fails. I am able to do this when I have a 2 step DAG (1st is Spark app, 2nd is dist-cp), however, when I have 2 spark apps, the cluster successfully runs the 1st step, and terminates without moving on to the 2nd and 3rd steps.

Through some digging, I can see that Airflow "pokes" steps to see if they are still running. In this instance, it seems to think that it's "Successful" only when 1 step is finished.

My spark apps are fairly simple. The first creates and writes a dataframe to local HDFS. The 2nd reads the data from HDFS and joins to another data set and writes back to HDFS. The third step is s3-dist-cp to copy the data from HDFS to s3. All 3 steps can be successfully run within Spark-Shell interactively, or as Spark-Submit jobs. I have also cloned the EMR cluster myself (without airflow) and saw all steps succeed without any errors, so EMR and Spark are not the issue here.

The DAG is below

```py
    from datetime import timedelta

    import airflow
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_create_job_flow_operator \
        import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
    from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_add_steps_operator \
        import EmrAddStepsOperator
    from airflow.contrib.sensors.emr_step_sensor import EmrStepSensor
    from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow_operator \
        import EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator

    DEFAULT_ARGS = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2)   
    }

    SPARK_TEST_STEPS = [
        {
            'Name': 'monthly_agg',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': ['spark-submit',
                          '--deploy-mode',
                           'cluster',
                          '--class' ,
                          'AggApp',
                          's3://jar1.jar' ]
                            }
        },   
        {
            'Name': 'monthly_agg2',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': ['spark-submit',
                          '--deploy-mode',
                           'cluster',
                          '--class' ,
                          'SimpleApp',
                          's3:/jar2.jar' ]
                            }
        },  

        {
            'Name': 'copy-data',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': ['s3-dist-cp',
                          '--src',
                          '/tempo',
                          '--dest',
                           's3://mydata/'
                        ]
                            }
        }
    ]

    JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Instances': {'Ec2SubnetId': 'subnet-mysubnetid', 
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': 'Master nodes',
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType': 'r4.2xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 1
            },
            {
                'Name': 'Slave nodes',
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
                'InstanceType': 'r4.2xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 8,
                'EbsConfiguration': {'EbsBlockDeviceConfigs':[{'VolumeSpecification':{'SizeInGB':128,'VolumeType':'gp2'},'VolumesPerInstance':1}],'EbsOptimized':True}
            }
        ]},
        'Name':'airflow-monthly_agg_custom',
        'Configurations': [
        {
        'Classification':'spark-defaults','Properties':
            {'spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled':'true',
            'spark.serializer':'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
            'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version':'2',
            "maximizeResourceAllocation":"true"},
        'Configurations':[]
        },
        {
        'Classification':'spark-hive-site','Properties':
        {'hive.metastore.client.factory.class':'com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory'}, 
        'Configurations':[]
        }
        ]}

    dag = DAG(
        'monthly_agg_custom',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=4),
        schedule_interval='@once'
    )

    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='add_steps',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=SPARK_TEST_STEPS,
        dag=dag
    )

    step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_step',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='remove_cluster',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    cluster_creator.set_downstream(step_adder)
    step_adder.set_downstream(step_checker)
    step_checker.set_downstream(cluster_remover)
```

Comment: using this DAG as a workaround - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_automatic_steps.py.

It won't perform all the steps as the above, and will lean on EMR to auto-terminate once steps are completed.

Comment: what was the solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are feeding `EmrStepSensor` all steps in as one `stepadder`, so as soon as one finishes, it  terminates the cluster.

The solution is to separate all steps and give the last step'id to the `EmrStepSensor`. Alternatively, you can only the last step with its separate step adder (`step_adder_actual_step`) from others and provided it to `EmrStepSensor`

```
step_adder_pre_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='pre_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=pre_step,
    dag=dag
)

step_adder_actual_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='actual_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=actual_step,
    dag=dag
)

step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
    task_id='watch_step',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('actual_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)

cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='remove_cluster',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    dag=dag
)

cluster_creator >> step_adder_pre_step >> step_adder_actual_step >> step_checker >> cluster_remover
```